# Program crashes when running on Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, crash, osx-snow-leopard, sigabrt

So I wrote an app for Mac. Everything works properly on my Mac laptop (Mountain Lion), but when I try to run it on another Mac (Snow Leopard) I get the following crash report when I try to open the app:

```
Process:         App [20844]
Path:            /Volumes/USB/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App
Identifier:      com.mathnerdproductions.App
Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [103]

Date/Time:       2012-09-05 17:22:26.403 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          19110167 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           142
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  2 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      D1555D0E-E1BC-4FE0-AABD-D059BAC03233

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (NSLayoutConstraint)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84cd8784 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff80b47f03 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84cd85a7 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 103
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84cd8534 +[NSException raise:format:] + 148
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff83305d0a _decodeObjectBinary + 2427
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff83306a89 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1229
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff83306fc9 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 462
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff83305d83 _decodeObjectBinary + 2548
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff833051fd _decodeObject + 208
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff83fb3389 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 2102
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff83305d83 _decodeObjectBinary + 2548
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff833051fd _decodeObject + 208
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff83fb2a41 loadNib + 146
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff83fb1fa1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 248
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff83fb1dd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff83faf35b NSApplicationMain + 279
16  App                    0x0000000100001662 main + 34
17  App                    0x0000000100001634 start + 52
)


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8144b0b6 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff814eb9f6 abort + 83
2   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff82a4f5d2 __tcf_0 + 0
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff80b4bb39 _objc_terminate + 100
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff82a4dae1 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 11
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff82a4db16 __cxxabiv1::__unexpected(void (*)()) + 0
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff82a4dbfc __gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff80b47fa2 object_getIvar + 0
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84cd85a7 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 103
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84cd8534 +[NSException raise:format:] + 148
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83305d0a _decodeObjectBinary + 2427
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83306a89 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1229
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83306fc9 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 462
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83305d83 _decodeObjectBinary + 2548
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff833051fd _decodeObject + 208
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fb3389 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 2102
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83305d83 _decodeObjectBinary + 2548
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff833051fd _decodeObject + 208
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fb2a41 loadNib + 146
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fb1fa1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 248
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fb1dd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83faf35b NSApplicationMain + 279
22  ...roductions.App   0x0000000100001662 main + 34
23  ...roductions.App   0x0000000100001634 start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81415c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81417add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff814177b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff814172de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81416c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81416aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81416a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81416e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81416aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff813fcd7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff813fd3ed mach_msg + 59
2   com.unsanity.ape                0x0000000100485f8f __ape_agent + 201
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81435fd6 _pthread_start + 331
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81435e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff702922f8  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfe5d8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x000000000000516c  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe5f0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe5d8
r8: 0x00007fff70295a60   r9: 0x0000000000000063  r10: 0x00007fff814470fa  r11: 0x0000000000000202
r12: 0x00007fff84d5db09  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000011
rip: 0x00007fff8144b0b6  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x00007fff7054bfd0

Binary Images:
   0x100000000 -        0x100006ff7 +com.mathnerdproductions.App 1.0 (1) <377A60C8-832D-3A6E-8F6B-E20BDE899B66> /Volumes/USB/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App
   0x100483000 -        0x100498ff7 +com.unsanity.ape 2.6.1 (2.6.1) <751AA5E7-ED1A-3B2F-5845-799AFD585CC7> /Library/Frameworks/ApplicationEnhancer.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationEnhancer
   0x1004f0000 -        0x1004f3ff7 +com.insecurity.eSellHijack ??? (1.0) <0FE31FDB-AA3D-9C47-423E-8A5F2B6A337A> /Library/Application Enhancers/eSell Hijack.ape/Contents/MacOS/eSell Hijack
   0x100783000 -        0x10079afff +com.eSellerate.EWSMac67108872 4.0.0.8 (4.0.0.8) <7E414F1D-8098-6CB9-8D8D-F1FAFABC5937> /Library/Frameworks/EWSMac.framework/EWSMac67108872
0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <DB8B8AB0-0C97-B51C-BE8B-B79895735A33> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff80003000 -     0x7fff80023ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.14) <15CF4C96-372D-C706-A237-47D20D2CAA6B> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x7fff80213000 -     0x7fff80229fef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <0321D32C-9FE1-3919-E03E-2530A0C1191B> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x7fff8022a000 -     0x7fff80235fff  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport 10.6.7 (258) <A2CBB18C-BD1C-8650-9091-7687E780E689> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
0x7fff80236000 -     0x7fff8073fff7  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle 3.14.0 (646) <75A96BFC-1832-808B-F430-C4C9379C5A98> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
0x7fff80770000 -     0x7fff80795ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x7fff80796000 -     0x7fff80796ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <15DF8B4A-96B2-CB4E-368D-DEC7DF6B62BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x7fff807cd000 -     0x7fff807defff  com.apple.DSObjCWrappers.Framework 10.6 (134) <CF1D9C05-8D77-0FFE-38E8-63D8A23E92E1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Versions/A/DSObjCWrappers
0x7fff8081a000 -     0x7fff8081dff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <75819794-3B7A-8944-D004-7EA6DD7CE836> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x7fff80844000 -     0x7fff80982fff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <96C5E9A6-C28C-E9CC-A0DB-27801A22A49F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x7fff80983000 -     0x7fff80aa2fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x7fff80aa3000 -     0x7fff80b3dfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2DE8987F-4563-4D8E-45C3-2F6F786E120D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x7fff80b3e000 -     0x7fff80bf4ff7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff80bf5000 -     0x7fff80bf5ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <96FB6BAD-5568-C4E0-6FA7-02791A58B584> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x7fff80c40000 -     0x7fff80c88ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <98FC4457-F405-0262-00F7-56119CA107B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x7fff80cb9000 -     0x7fff80ccdff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <574C1BE0-5E5E-CCAF-06F8-92A69CB2892D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x7fff80d19000 -     0x7fff80d1fff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x7fff80d20000 -     0x7fff80d20ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <4CCE5D69-F1B3-8FD3-1483-E0271DB2CCF3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x7fff80d21000 -     0x7fff80d36ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <DC999B32-BF41-94C8-0583-27D9AB463E8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x7fff80d37000 -     0x7fff80dd7fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x7fff80dd8000 -     0x7fff80f97fff  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.5 (3.0.5) <175E97F1-B1A7-655A-F154-5B6ACC5F3985> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x7fff811d3000 -     0x7fff8121dff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <DE238BE4-5E22-C4D5-CF5C-3D50FDEE4701> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x7fff81360000 -     0x7fff813dffe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x7fff813e0000 -     0x7fff813e6ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <AAB5CC56-334A-3C60-3C27-54E8F34D754E> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x7fff813e7000 -     0x7fff813e8ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <A91CE5B9-3C63-5F8C-5052-95CCAB866F72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x7fff813e9000 -     0x7fff813fbfe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <30FE378B-99FE-8C7C-06D0-A3AA0A0A70D4> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x7fff813fc000 -     0x7fff815bdfef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x7fff817bd000 -     0x7fff818d7fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <D1650AED-02EF-EFB3-100E-064C7F018745> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x7fff818d8000 -     0x7fff818d8ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x7fff818d9000 -     0x7fff81901fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x7fff81902000 -     0x7fff8193cfff  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <7982734A-B66B-44AA-DEEC-364D2C10009B> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x7fff8193d000 -     0x7fff819bafef  com.apple.backup.framework 1.2.2 (1.2.2) <BB72F0C7-20E2-76DC-6764-5B93A7AC0EB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x7fff819bb000 -     0x7fff81a25fe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <7BD7F19B-ACD4-186C-B42D-4DEBA6795628> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x7fff81bbe000 -     0x7fff81bcdfef  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <ECAE2D12-5BE3-46E7-6EE5-563B80B32A3E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x7fff81bd8000 -     0x7fff81bd9fff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <D0666597-B331-C43C-67BB-F2E754079A7A> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x7fff81bda000 -     0x7fff81bdcfff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <B422DA26-E0CF-F280-6EB4-3B8FEF59B665> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x7fff81bdd000 -     0x7fff81c9ffe7  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <EF06F16C-0CC9-B4CA-7BD9-0A97FA967340> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x7fff81ca0000 -     0x7fff81f29ff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <0D80504C-9A6D-C865-AF37-7C231ACF97CB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x7fff81f8b000 -     0x7fff82149fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <4274FC73-A257-3A56-4293-5968F3428854> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x7fff82153000 -     0x7fff82159ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <04EDCEDE-E36F-15F8-DC67-E61E149D2C9A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x7fff8215a000 -     0x7fff8248efef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x7fff8248f000 -     0x7fff82500ff7  com.apple.AppleVAFramework 4.10.27 (4.10.27) <6CDBA3F5-6C7C-A069-4716-2B6C3AD5001F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVA
0x7fff8255f000 -     0x7fff825effff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <45BA1053-9196-3C2F-2421-AFF5E09627CC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x7fff82656000 -     0x7fff82661ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <C359B93B-CC9B-FC0B-959E-FB10674103A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x7fff82662000 -     0x7fff8268dff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <3630A97F-55C1-3F34-CA63-3847653C9645> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x7fff8268e000 -     0x7fff82713ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x7fff82714000 -     0x7fff82715ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <49B723D1-85F8-F86C-2331-F586C56D68AF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x7fff82785000 -     0x7fff8278afff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <6BBC351E-40B3-F4EB-2F35-05BDE52AF87E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x7fff8278b000 -     0x7fff827a1fe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x7fff827a2000 -     0x7fff82852fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x7fff828ab000 -     0x7fff828afff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x7fff828b0000 -     0x7fff828c9fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
0x7fff828ca000 -     0x7fff828edfff  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x7fff828ee000 -     0x7fff8293dff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <01B370FB-D524-F660-3826-E85B7F0D85CD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x7fff8293e000 -     0x7fff829f3fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <A68339AA-909D-E46C-35C0-72808EE3D043> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x7fff82a03000 -     0x7fff82a80fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x7fff82a81000 -     0x7fff82d7ffff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x7fff82d80000 -     0x7fff82e39fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x7fff82e6a000 -     0x7fff82eb6fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x7fff82eb7000 -     0x7fff83254fe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x7fff83255000 -     0x7fff83269fff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x7fff832e1000 -     0x7fff832f8fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <79AB2131-2A6C-F351-38A9-ED58B25534FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x7fff832f9000 -     0x7fff8357bfff  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <E10E4DB4-9D5E-54A8-3FB6-2A82426066E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x7fff837ec000 -     0x7fff8382dfef  com.apple.CoreMedia 0.484.60 (484.60) <6B73A514-C4D5-8DC7-982C-4E4F0231ED77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
0x7fff8386d000 -     0x7fff839a2fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <F4814A13-E557-59AF-30FF-E62929367933> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x7fff839a3000 -     0x7fff83a80fff  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x7fff83a81000 -     0x7fff83ab2fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <562565E1-AA65-FE96-13FF-437410C886D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x7fff83ab3000 -     0x7fff83ab6ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <0234B95B-A339-4576-BB0D-A568634B50F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x7fff83b84000 -     0x7fff83b84ff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <C69E895A-1C66-3DA9-5F63-8BE85DB9C4E1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x7fff83bd0000 -     0x7fff83bf7ff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <32EDAB18-08ED-B31A-D2BD-12EFFE60D83C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x7fff83c30000 -     0x7fff83c77ff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <31118426-355F-206A-65AB-CCA2D2D3EBD7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x7fff83c88000 -     0x7fff83d6dfef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x7fff83e7b000 -     0x7fff83e8cff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5BAFAE5C-2307-C27B-464D-582A10A6990B> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x7fff83f11000 -     0x7fff83f20fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x7fff83f21000 -     0x7fff83f6aff7  com.apple.securityinterface 4.0.1 (40418.0.1) <9AF33A9F-2D8C-2AE6-868C-EA836C861031> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
0x7fff83f6b000 -     0x7fff83facfff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <78D48D27-A9C4-62CA-2803-D0BBED82855A> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x7fff83fad000 -     0x7fff849a7ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x7fff84ae2000 -     0x7fff84b03fff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9410EC7F-4D24-6740-AFEE-90405750FAD7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x7fff84b04000 -     0x7fff84b4dfef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <B0F4CA55-445F-E901-0FCF-47B3B4BAE6E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x7fff84b4e000 -     0x7fff84b69ff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <DC329CD4-1159-A40A-A769-70CAA70F601A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
0x7fff84c27000 -     0x7fff84d9efe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <BB4E5158-E47A-39D3-2561-96CB49FA82D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x7fff84e57000 -     0x7fff84e65ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x7fff84e66000 -     0x7fff84ef2fef  SecurityFoundation 36840.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <105C82B6-A1C7-9082-ECA6-AEA08C1948C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x7fff84ef3000 -     0x7fff84f34fef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x7fff8572b000 -     0x7fff85f35fe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2F26CDC7-DAE9-9ABE-6806-93BBBDA20DA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x7fff85f36000 -     0x7fff85f73fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1) <F3B7B267-D580-F287-6DE7-8AC91C92AB35> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x7fff85f74000 -     0x7fff85faffff  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x7fff85fb0000 -     0x7fff85fb5ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <8B088D78-E508-6622-E477-E34C22CF2F67> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x7fff85fcc000 -     0x7fff8601fff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x7fff860d2000 -     0x7fff86150ff7  com.apple.CoreText 151.12 (???) <5BE797B7-C903-B664-ADD9-7514B1A6EF9E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x7fff862f8000 -     0x7fff869f4ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x7fff869f5000 -     0x7fff86a33fe7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <395D7C0D-36B5-B353-0DC8-51ABC0B1C030> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x7fff86a34000 -     0x7fff86b4aff7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <3814FCF9-92B9-A6AB-E76A-F7021894AA3F> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x7fff86b6c000 -     0x7fff86b6cff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <32BD355E-C7C7-B993-12F4-90E70C3F3B10> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x7fff86eb1000 -     0x7fff86eeeff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <F743389F-F25A-A77D-4FCA-D6B01AF2EE6D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
0x7fff86f72000 -     0x7fff86f93fe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <A6BF1360-1B23-78BD-12EF-E4A5753EEB76> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x7fff86f94000 -     0x7fff87051fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <BBB8888E-18DE-5D09-3C3A-F4C029EC7886> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x7fff873e4000 -     0x7fff874a5fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.8 (4.6.8) <7DF1D175-6451-51A2-DBBF-40FCA78C0D2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x7fff87500000 -     0x7fff87670fff  com.apple.QTKit 7.7 (1790) <04FA6686-0570-78BC-7D24-9CFFC87CBE87> /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
0x7fff87671000 -     0x7fff876c6ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <F09541B6-5E28-1C01-C1AE-F6A2508670C7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls

Model: iMac11,3, BootROM IM112.0057.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.93 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 1.59f2
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5750, ATI Radeon HD 5750, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 2.1.14.6
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD1001FALS-40Y6A0, 931.51 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: DataTraveler 2.0, 0x0951  (Kingston Technology Company), 0x1607, 0xfa130000 / 7
USB Device: FreeAgent GoFlex, 0x0bc2  (Seagate LLC), 0x5021, 0xfa140000 / 5
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8502, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

In XCode, the deployment target is set to 10.6 and no errors occur when archiving the program. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface files can have different deployment targets, and it sounds like yours may be set to 10.8 or 10.7. Look in the File Inspector for your .xib (you can right-click it and choose Show File Inspector) and look at Deployment.

Specifically, yours is failing trying to unpack an NSLayoutConstraint which was introduced in 10.7.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem (10.8)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are not using `autolayout`, as that is not supported in OS X versions 10.6 and prior.

You can check this by opening up your XIB file and checking the document properties. Make sure the "Use Autolayout" box is unchecked.